# How to create a counter for the number of times a button that was created was pressed in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I have made a simple program that allows me to type a label for a button and have it created and clickable in the tkinter gui. Now all I need is to add a function that returns the number of times each individual button is clicked. The problem is that the buttons I created are not actually coded in the input so I've found it difficult to do this. I feel like I would have to use the lambda function but I have no experience at all with it. Help is appreciated, thank you.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Tkinter FINAL")
window.geometry("600x400")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

counter_name = tk.Label(window, text="Counter Word", width=20)
counter_name.place(x=460,y=318)
counter_entry = tk.Entry(window, width=20)
counter_entry.place(x=470,y=338)

position_x = 0
position_y = 0


word_dict = {}
def button_function():
    word_dict[title] += 1

button_count = 0
def button_maker():
    global position_x, position_y, button_count, title
    button = tk.Button(window, text=counter_entry.get(), width=10, height=2, command = button_function, fg="red")
    button.place(x=position_x,y=position_y)
    position_x += 116
    button_count += 1
    if button_count % 6 == 0:
        position_y += 50
        position_x = 0
    title = counter_entry.get()
    word_dict[title] = 0
    counter_entry.delete(0,'end')




btnmaker = tk.Button(window, text='Click to create counter', width=17, height=2, command = button_maker, fg="red")
btnmaker.place(x=470,y=358)



btnreset = tk.Button(window, text='RESET', width=10, height=2, command = window.destroy, fg="red")
btnreset.place(x=520,y=500)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code already does this, right?  All you have to do is dump the `word_dict` array.  The dictionary keys match the button titles.  Put another way, I think you have already written the program!

Comment: `button.configure(command=lambda btn=button: button_function(btn))` inside `button_maker` after you create button. Also, note that your `button_function` must take a parameter. Another way would be to bind `button_function` to the `<1>` event. Now you don't need the lambda function and can know which button was clicked using `<parameter>.widget` here parameter is ur `button_function` parameter.

Comment: @TimRoberts what do you mean by dictionary keys match button titles? I don't have a dictionary in my code.

Comment: how would `button_function` take a parameter?

Comment: Why not use `grid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the word entered to `button_function()` using `lambda`:

```py
word_dict = {}

def button_function(word):
    word_dict[word] += 1
    print(word, word_dict[word])

def button_maker():
    # get the input word
    word = counter_entry.get().strip()
    # make sure the input word is unique in the dictionary
    if word and word not in word_dict:
        count = len(word_dict)
        button = tk.Button(window, text=word, width=10, height=2, fg="red",
                           command=lambda w=word: button_function(w)) # pass the input word to button_function()
        button.place(x=count%5*116, y=count//5*60)
        word_dict[word] = 0  # init the counter for the input word
        counter_entry.delete(0,'end')
```

---

Updated code with counter labels:

```py
word_dict = {}

def button_function(word):
    count = word_dict[word].get()
    word_dict[word].set(count+1)

def button_maker():
    word = counter_entry.get().strip()
    if word and word not in word_dict:
        count = len(word_dict)
        row, col = count//5*2, count%5
        # create the word button
        button = tk.Button(window, text=word, width=10, height=2, fg="red",
                           command=lambda w=word: button_function(w))
        button.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=10, pady=(10,0))
        # create the corresponding counter label        
        var = tk.IntVar() # for the counter value
        tk.Label(window, textvariable=var).grid(row=row+1, column=col)
        word_dict[word] = var
        counter_entry.delete(0, 'end')
```

Comment: Thank you, this works very well. Now how would i also allow this counter to take place under the buttons in the gui itself? In other words when i press a button in the gui the number 1 pops up beneath and then keeps incrementing per click?

Comment: Create a label and then `config()` its text inside the function to take text as `word_dict[word]`.